# How to use ARRAY with a DO loop & counter+1 statement?

Tags: sas, ssas

I am trying to determine the number of observations that have a specific diagnosis in a specified range.
In doing so, I want to set an indicator that will increment if the ID# has more than 1 value in that range. For example, I have 10 patients with 5 different diagnoses but I want to check if they only have it in a specified range between 7-9. My data looks something like this

```
data 1;
input id r1-r5;
datalines;
1 8 4 5 6 3
2 4 8 7 2 1
3 1 3 5 9 4
4 2 3 3 6 5
;
```

I want the new data table to look like this

```
data 2;
input id r1-r5 newvar;
datalines;
1 8 4 5 6 3 1
2 4 8 7 2 1 2
3 1 3 5 9 4 1
4 2 3 3 6 5 0
etc..
```

After I ran my code, it deletes all IDs that do not have a number in that range, so ID 4 would be gone, but it adds another row to ID 2 because it has two variables in that range. So say I had 30 observations & only 10 had variables in that range. I would only get 10 observations shown in the new data set but i want all 30.

My code;

```
DATA 2 (drop=i);
  set 1;
  array rx (10) r1-r5 ;
  newvar=0 ;
  do i= 1 to 5;
  if 6<rx(i)<10 then do;
  newvar+1;
    output;
    end;
    end;
```

I may possibly have to add a reinitialize statement of newvar=0 after the output but it still gives me the same results.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really want the observation where NEWVAR is zero?

Answer (score 0):

Move the OUTPUT statement to the proper place.  After you have finished counting.  If you don't want to remove any of the observations then just get rid of the OUTPUT statement.

```
DATA two ;
  set one;
  array rx r1-r5 ;
  newvar=0 ;
  do i= 1 to 5;
    if 6<rx(i)<10 then do;
      newvar+1;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

Otherwise to only keep the observations that have at least one of the conditions then test the value of NEWVAR after the do loops.

```
...
  if newvar>0 then output;
run;
```

Comment: Ahhh thank you! No wonder it would not work. I got it! Thanks!